# Ansible idiomatic destination/dest based on a conditional

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm writing a play that ideally updates a block in a file, but the destination file can be any of roughy 20 files based on some condition. While this is undoubtedly wrong, what I want is something like:

```
- name: update files
  hosts: localhost
  user: myself
  tasks:
    - blockinfile:
      dest: /home/me/file1
        when: {{ condition }} == True
      dest: /home/me/file2
        when: {{ condition2 }} == True

      ...

      block: |
        data
        data

      ...
```

Is there an idiomatic or proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a bit convoluted and I have a feeling that if you step back from the problem you could probably think of a better solution. However, with the information provided I'd say move the logic into a variable and then use the variable as the destination.

So you'd have some vars file (such as a role defaults or an environment group vars or even an included vars file) like this:

```
rolename_blockinfile_dest: '{% if condition %}/home/me/file1{% elif condition2 %}/home/me/file2{% endif %}'
```

And then just the following in your task:

```
...
  tasks:
    - blockinfile:
      dest: '{{ rolename_blockinfile_dest }}'
...
```

Comment: Yeah, that ended up being the smart way to do it. I just created an environment variable for it and inject that in during the build process. Thanks for the tip!